# Bind to LDAP after SSO?

Tags: php, python, ldap, single-sign-on, saml

I have this web application with LDAP backend, to read and modify some LDAP attributes.
Web application use the SSO (Single Sign-on) to authenticate user.

How can I bind to LDAP, if I only get a user name as an attribute from SSO, withouth asking for password again, because it will make SSO useless?

I use SimpleSAMLphp as identity provider, and python driven web application for LDAP management.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than using the user's credentials to bind to LDAP, get an application account at LDAP that has read permissions for the attributes you need on the users within the directory. Then, when you get the username via SSO, you just query LDAP using your application's ID.

Make sure you make your application ID's password super strong - 64 chars with a yearly change should be good. Better yet, do certificate-based authn.